# Entity Framework method group Include does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading, method-group

I have some troubles with **Loading Related Entities** with a method group in EF.

In simple queries the **Loading of Related Entities** works ok with `Include`.

For example:

```
var result =
    Repository.Query<TimeState>(x => x.Accepted == 0 && x.ProjectID != null && myTeam.Contains(x.EmployeeID))
                       .Include(typeof(Project).Name)
                       .Include(typeof(Employee).Name)
                       .Include(typeof(EmployeeDetails).Name)
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmitedDate);
```

Works perfect, and Loads the Project and the Employee

but in the next query does not load the Project and the Employee

```
var result2 = from item in Repository.Query<TimeState>(x => x.Accepted == 0 && x.ProjectID != null)
                                               .Include(typeof(Project).Name)
                                               .Include(typeof(Employee).Name)
                                               .Include(typeof(EmployeeDetails).Name)
               let projectId = (int)item.ProjectID
               let isA = projectsIds.Contains(projectId) && item.Employee.EmployeeDetails.SuperiorID == id
               let isB = item.Project.ManagerID == id && employeesTeam.Contains(item.EmployeeID)
               where isA || isB
               orderby item.SubmitedDate descending
               select item;
```

I tried to do such a change: `select new { item, item.Employee, item.Project };`

```
var result3 = from item in Repository.Query<TimeState>(x => x.Accepted == 0 && x.ProjectID != null)
                                               .Include(typeof(Project).Name)
                                               .Include(typeof(Employee).Name)
                                               .Include(typeof(EmployeeDetails).Name)
               let projectId = (int)item.ProjectID
               let isA = projectsIds.Contains(projectId) && item.Employee.EmployeeDetails.SuperiorID == id
               let isB = item.Project.ManagerID == id && employeesTeam.Contains(item.EmployeeID)
               where isA || isB
               orderby item.SubmitedDate descending
               select new { item, item.Employee, item.Project };
```

After that, `result3[0].Employee` has a value, the same for `result3[0].Project` (or any other item from that collection).
The problem is that I don't need the Employee and the Project as separate properties in this dynamic object **result3**.

How is possible to have Employee and Project in the method which returns result2 ? :)

Comment: what happens when you access `Project` or `Employee` from `result2`?

Comment: By the way, why did you rollback marc_s's edit? IMO that edit improved the readability of our question.

Comment: @Default , in `result2` the `Employee` and the `Project` are NULL.

Comment: @Default, answer for your second question: unfortunately, was an edit which transformed my types `Employee` and `Project` into simple words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rarely use query syntax, and I've never run into someone using .Include(typeof(..).Name) syntax so try the following:

```
var result2 = (from item in Repository.Query<TimeState>(x => x.Accepted == 0 && x.ProjectID != null)
               let projectId = (int)item.ProjectID
               let isA = projectsIds.Contains(projectId) && item.Employee.EmployeeDetails.SuperiorID == id
               let isB = item.Project.ManagerID == id && employeesTeam.Contains(item.EmployeeID)
               where isA || isB
               orderby item.SubmitedDate descending
               select item)
  .Include(i=>i.Projects)
  .Include(i=>i.Employees)
  .Include(i=>i.EmployeeDetails);
```

You may need to include `using System.Data.Entity;` as well for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. :) It works (I had already the `using System.Data.Entity;` in `*.cs` file header)

Comment: BTW, which query syntax do you prefer? (may it will be a better chose for me too :) )

Comment: I typically use the method/lambda syntax.